# Which database is TFS 2018 using?

Tags: sql-server, tfs

I am working with TFS 2018 and trying to find out how to know which databeses it uses.
I've found out this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/admin/backup/backup-db-architecture

This works for the default databases.

However, in my specific case I have more databases in SQL Server that the ones which are shown in this URL.
As so, I wanted do be sure which databases is my TFS using.

Is there a way to check what are all the databases used by my TFS 2018?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you're looking for the database used by each collection?  If so, to find the **collection database** used by each collection open the Team Foundation Server Administrator console and go to the Team Project Collections node which is under Application Tier.  From there, find the collection you're searching for, highlight this, and press the Edit Settings button.  The database used by this collection will be in the Database field on the window that comes up.  You've probably already verified this, but for the **configuration database** go to the Application Tier node.  The configuration database will be the database in the Initial Catalog of the connection string.  You can find the connection string in the Data Tier Summary area.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your answer. What about the other databases (TFS_Warehouse, TFS_Analysis, ReportServer, ReportServerTempDB, WSS_Config, WSS_Content, WSS_AdminContent, VirtualManagerDB). I thinkl their names can be changed is that right? If the names are not the default ones, is there a way to find it?

Comment: For the warehouse, analysis, etc. databases have you checked the Reporting node(also under Application Tier)?  I haven't used the the SharePoint feature (WSS databases) but I'd look under the SharePoint Web Applications node for these.  For the VirtualManagerDB try the checking the SCVMM Settings under Lab Management.